# The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following views.py

```
class FilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = cds_composite_csv
    serializer_class = cds_compositeSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
    model = get_model('markit', 'cds_composite_csv')
    filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')
    if UserFile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, file__filename=filename).exists():
        queryset = model.objects.using('markitdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
        return queryset
    else:
        content = {
            'status': 'Request Failed.'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

I understand the reason it's failing is because of the else and the fact that it's trying to use the serializer from the class view.  How do I get it to ignore the serializer if the else clause is met?

Comment: The reason its failing is the `get_queryset` method should always return a queryset, and should not return a http response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want explicitly to return `'status':'Request Failed'`?
I would rather place `raise Http404` in the `else` block and remove everything else.
If I was supposed to write a client to consume your API I would first of all check if I got status code 200 before I proceed further. Here I would get 'HTTP 200 OK', but not an expected result.

The above is just one possible solution, you could also make try-except or maybe something else, but I would certainly advise against custom `Request failed`. It's just my opinion.